# Inserting the name of files with specific file extension inside a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need to write the filenames of some .mp4 files into a csv file. In my folder there are a large number of .mp4 files and also there are other folders inside my folders. I only need to write the file name of the mentioned .mp4 files inside the csv file. The CSV file needs to follow this rule that the firs element in the first row should be 0 and in the other rows the names of the .mp4 files should be written down. Also, Since the name some of the .mp4 files start with a number and afterward there are some text name after that number (like: 113_ddd_r). I need that only the number to be inserted inside the CSV file and not the text to be inserted.

In this regard, I found the following solution from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329952/11140344) but it is not corresponding to my needs. How I can modify that?

```
import os
import csv

path = 'YOUR_INPUT_DIRECTORY'

with open('YOUR_OUTPUT_FILE', 'wb') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  writer.writerow(['identifier', 'file', 'description', 'subject[0]', 'title', 'creator', 'date', 'collection'])
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        writer.writerow(['', os.path.join(root,filename), '','','', 'opensource','',''])
```

Comment: Its still not entirely clear what you want. By filename you mean the name without extension? And what do you mean by only the "mentioned" mp4 files? Seeing an example of a directory structure with files and the output you want would help.

Comment: What is "mentioned " .mp4 files? What have you really tried to solve this? Asking us to modify some arbitrary code for you will not do

Comment: Is your core issue that you don't know how to produce the "index" or slice the filename to get the pieces of data you want in your csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a folder called "mp4" and wrote the following files to this directory:

```
% ls mp4
1_hello.mp4 2_hello.mp4 33_test.mp4 hello.mp4   test.txt
```

Then I created a Python script called `script.py`.

My directory looks like this:

```
% ls
mp4     script.py
```

Here is the code for `script.py`

```
import os
import csv
import re

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    pattern = '^(\d+).*\.mp4$'
    headers = ['identifier', 'file', 'description', 'subject', 'title', 'creator', 'date', 'collection']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('mp4'):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
                m = re.match(pattern, filename)
                if m:
                    filename = m.group(1) + '.mp4'
                file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                writer.writerow(['', file, '', '', '', 'opensource', '', ''])

print('Finished writing to file.csv')
```

You can see that I use the os and csv modules, and I also use the re (regex) module.

The re module lets me check whether a string matches a pattern, and capture a group of characters in the match.

I check every filename for the pattern `<number><text>.mp4`. When a filename starts with a number, I capture that number, and use it to create a new string `<number>.mp4`.

Now let's run the script and see what the output looks like.

```
% python script.py
Finished writing to file.csv

% cat file.csv
identifier,file,description,subject,title,creator,date,collection
,mp4/1.mp4,,,,opensource,,
,mp4/hello.mp4,,,,opensource,,
,mp4/2.mp4,,,,opensource,,
,mp4/33.mp4,,,,opensource,,
```

The logic we are using is this:

> If the filename starts with a number and ends with .mp4, capture the
> number, and record the filename as `<number>.mp4`.
>
> Else, if the filename ends with .mp4, record the filename as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because the pattern of the names in my files is like 1_home.mp4, 7_home.mp4, I need to have a csv file that only containes the numbers in the name of the files and not the string piece of them in a column in the csv file without containing other information and also titles. Moreover, the names of the files are needed to be stored from the second row and in the first row it is needed that 0 to be inserted.

Comment: Hi @dtr43 Thanks for your comment. At the moment I can say this: the re module (which is short for regex) can help you get the numbers in each filename. The re module allows you to (1) check whether a string matches a pattern and (2) capture a group of characters in the match, such as a string of numbers.